# Why is the code with multiple Do slower than the one without them, and why is For faster than Do?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, syntax, compile

For some table `tab` having `N` rows and `n` columns, I need to go over all its rows $j$ and columns $f$ and sum some expression depending on the `tab`s elements:

$$
\text{count} = \sum_{j = 1}^{N}\sum_{f_{1} = 1}^{n-1}\sum_{f_{2} = f_{1}+1}^{n}\text{expression}(\text{tab}_{j,f_{1}},\text{tab}_{j,f_{2}})
$$

Here is my code assuming that the expression is just some boolean condition:

```
ncols = 2;
tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^7, ncols}];
comp1 = Hold@Compile[{{tab, _Real, 2}}, Module[{el1, el2, count},
      count = 0;
      (*Cycle over rows*)
      Do[
       (*Cycle over f1*)
       Do[
        el1 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, f1];
        (*Cycle over f2*)
        Do[
         el2 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, f2];
         (*adding to count*)
         count += Boole[el1*el2 > 0.4 && el1^2 + el2^2 < 0.9]
         , {f2, f1 + 1, ncols, 1}]
        , {f1, 1, ncols - 1, 1}]
       , {j, 1, Length[tab], 1}];
      count], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   OwnValues@ncols // ReleaseHold
```

The code structure is convenient for my real task (see below), so I want to preserve it.

Another version uses `For` instead of `Do`:

```
comp3 = Hold@
    Compile[{{tab, _Real, 2}}, Module[{el1, el2, count, j, f1, f2},
      count = 0;
      (*Cycle over rows*)
      For[j = 1, j <= Length[tab], j++,
       For[f1 = 1, f1 <= ncols - 1, f1++,
        el1 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, f1];
        (*Cycle over f2*)
        For[f2 = f1 + 1, f2 <= ncols, f2++,
         el2 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, f2];
         (*adding to count*)
         count += Boole[el1*el2 > 0.4 && el1^2 + el2^2 < 0.9]]]];
      count], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
      OwnValues@ncols // ReleaseHold
```

For `n` = 2, the same summation may be done using this simple code:

```
comp2 = Hold@Compile[{{tab, _Real, 2}}, Module[{el1, el2, count},
      count = 0;
      Do[
       el1 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, 1];
       el2 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, 2];
       count += Boole[el1*el2 > 0.4 && el1^2 + el2^2 < 0.9]
       , {j, 1, Length[tab], 1}];
      count], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   OwnValues@ncols // ReleaseHold
```

`comp2` is much faster than `comp1`, faster than `comp3`, while `comp3` is faster than `comp1`

```
comp1[tab] // AbsoluteTiming
comp2[tab] // AbsoluteTiming
comp3[tab] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0745858,162135}

> {0.0325867,162135}

> {0.048013,162135}

The same timing hierarchy between `comp1`, `comp3` holds if increasing the number of columns in `tab`.

Could you please tell me what is the reason for the observed slowdown of `comp3`/`comp1` compared to `comp2`, and of `comp1` compared to `comp3` (the only difference is the replacement `Do`->`For`), and how to improve `comp1`/`comp3` if preserving a similar structure with the cycles?

**Edit**

After the changes from the answer by *Michael E2*, the timings are

> {0.0548117,162135}

> {0.0360111,162135}

> {0.04748,162135}

Still, the `Do` version is slower on my machine.

**P.S.**

I need this structure because in my real problem (illustrated in a simplified way by [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287399/why-are-the-results-of-these-codes-different)):

1. I do not just sum the elements but rather some values obtained using expressions involving these elements,
2. the expressions are computationally expensive,
3. and there are some additional conditions inside the summation (say, I may want to break the summation over the columns because of some reason).

**Update**
Consider the following code:

```
comp4 = Compile[{{tab, _Real, 2}}, 
  Module[{el1, el2, count, ncols, f1max},
   count = 0;
   ncols = (Length[Compile`GetElement[tab, 1]]*2)/2;
   f1max = ncols - 1;
   (*Cycle over rows*)
   Do[(*Cycle over f1*)
    Do[el1 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, f1];
     (*Cycle over f2*)
     Do[el2 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, f1 + f2];(*!*)
      (*adding to count*)
      count += Boole[el1*el2 > 0.4 && el1^2 + el2^2 < 0.9]
      , {f2, ncols - f1}],(*!*)
     {f1, f1max}],(*!*)
    {j, Length[tab]}];
   count], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
comp1[tab] // AbsoluteTiming
comp4[tab] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Note the string `(Length[CompileGetElement[tab, 1]]*2)/2;`. Normally, it is just `Length[CompileGetElement[tab, 1]]`. But the stupid code probably treats it without the simplification. As a result, `comp4` is evaluated 3 times slower than `comp1`. Maybe some analog of `Simplify` would work, but `Simplify` itself is not compilable.

Comment: Why don't you use `Sum` and `Map` and `Plus`/`Total`?

Comment: @lericr : because in my real problem I do not just sum the elements of the table but some values obtained using expressions which use these elements. I will add the clarification.

Comment: `Sum` can manage the indices.

Comment: @lericr : currently, I use this `Do` structure for the code from this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287399/why-are-the-results-of-these-codes-different (the actual relevant code is `acceptanceOptimized`). I have doubts about whether `Sum` may be used there. That's why I prefer (in the lack of other ways) to keep `Do` in this example.

Comment: (1) In compiling to WVM, Mma constructs have limitations that facilitate translation to (optimized) C-like code. (2) In my own head-to-head test of triply nested `Do[]` v. `For[]`, `For[]` still lags behind `Do[]` by quite a bit (5X slower in WVM, 30K X slower in C!). A moderately slow calculation in the body of the loop might make that overhead insignificant. My conclusion is that **compiled `For[]` is still slower than `Do[]`.**

Comment: @MichaelE2 : but why in this case `For` is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit seems to be an `IteratorCountI[]` instruction when `Do[]` has a variable starting point. In this case in the inner loop `{f2, f1+1, ncols}`. I have no idea why this should be so slow.

```
ncols = 2;
tab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^7, ncols}];
comp1 = Hold@Compile[{{tab, _Real, 2}},
      Module[{el1, el2, count},
       count = 0;
       (*Cycle over rows*)
       Do[
        (*Cycle over f1*)
        Do[
         el1 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, f1];
         (*Cycle over f2*)
         Do[
          el2 = Compile`GetElement[tab, j, f1 + f2]; (* ! *)
          (*adding to count*)
          count += Boole[el1*el2 > 0.4 && el1^2 + el2^2 < 0.9],
          {f2, ncols - f1}],                         (* ! *)
         {f1, "ncols-1"}],                           (* ! *)
        {j, Length[tab]}];
       count
       ],
      CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /.
     OwnValues@ncols /.
   "ncols-1" -> ncols - 1 // (* a slight efficiency *)
  ReleaseHold
```

Timings:

```
comp1[tab] // RepeatedTiming
comp2[tab] // RepeatedTiming
comp3[tab] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.010221,   162488}
  {0.00751259, 162488}
  {0.0145402,  162488}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks! And without this fix, you also had a significant slowdown of `comp1`?

Comment: @JohnTaylor For your original `comp1`, it was about 6X times slower than `comp2` (`0.044` s)  and 3X times slower than `comp3`. I think the `"ncols-1"` trick sped it up to 5X slower than `comp2` (`0.036` s). For some reason `ncols - 1` is optimized in `For[]` but not in `Do[]`. (It's computed each iteration in `Do[]` as `2 - 1`, instead of compiled as `1`).

Comment: And the CPU is M1?

Comment: Interesting. On my (much slower) machine, the new `comp1` is still slower (10-20%) than `comp3`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you please tell me how to apply a similar trick `"ncols-1"->ncols-1` in the following case? I have a table `tab` for which I define `ncols = Length[tab[[1]]]/x` inside the compiled code, where `x` is some integer. I do this outside all these `For`, `Do` of course. Then, I define `f1max = ncols - 1`, and then use `Do`/`For` as `f1, f1max`. However, the result is still evaluated somewhat slower than if I just replace `f1max` with 1.

Comment: Please see the bottom of my question for an explicit example.

Comment: Apparently division is parsed as returning a `Real`, which makes `ncols` be typed as a `Real`. You can declare types with initialization in `Module`: `Module[{el1 = 0., el2 = 0., count = 0, ncols = 0, f1max = 0},...]`. This adds minimal initialization overhead if done outside loops. You also need to explicitly cast the division to an integer: ``ncols = Floor[(Length[Compile`GetElement[tab, 1]]*2)/2];``.  BTW, I don't know much about `Compile`. It's all trial and error. We used to have a few users who seemed to know some of the internals. Like optimization...

Comment: ....This is not optimized the way you might expect: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[(Length[Compile`GetElement[tab, 1]]*2)/2 // Unevaluated, "OptimizationLevel" -> 2]``. This might be why, or it might be that `Length[..]*2/2` is type `Real` and `Length[..]` is type `Integer`; so no simplification. -- Passing a scalar argument to the `CompiledFunction` has minimal overhead. Why not pass `ncols = Length[tab[[1]]]/x`? I'm not sure the `ncols-1` trick is that robust.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!